# If an event action is a goal, would the event ever get traced but not the goal?

Tags: google-analytics

I have an Event Action set up as a Goal. I can see the events taking place in the events report, but the goal - for the same events - is not being picked up.

Why would that be?

So lets say I have an Event Action called "Submit_Form". Then I set up a goal called "Goal_A" where the the Goal details are "Action - Equals to - Submit_Form".

Would there ever be a situation where GA captures the event "Submit Form" but not the goal called "Goal_A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 cases where an event goal would not fire when the event happens.

1. The goal is not active. In the final column of Admin -> View -> Goals, Recording must be set to On.
2. The event has been triggered more than once in the same session. Goals are only recorded at most once per session, so subsequent event hits will not increase goal conversions.

If your issue is that the goal never fires, but it is recording, I would double check that the Event Action is completely identical between the event report and the goal settings. In the goal settings, changing the match type from "equals to" to "regular expression" and using the "verify this goal" link might help test whether there's a mismatch there.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.  Would including the Event Category in the Event Conditions for the Goal details effect how the goal is fired?

Comment: Only if it changed the set of applicable events - if you had a Submit_Form action inside two different categories, for example, it would restrict goal conversions to the category you set. But if Submit_Form is a unique action across all categories it will count the same with or without the category. We have event goals with only some of the fields filled out and they work as expected.